# How to quickly test the existence and value of a nested boolean with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, if-statement

Often times, I have to check an object's deeply nested boolean value to see whether it exists and if so, whether it is `true` or `false`.

Let's say, I want to check if `payload.options.save` is set to `false`, but I do not know if `document` and `options` even exist in the `payload` object.

Currently, I do that:

```
if (payload && payload.document && payload.document.options && payload.document.options.save && payload.document.options.save === false) {
    resolve(payload);
    return;
}
```

Is there a shorter way to check that?

Comment: you can remove last check from condition `&& payload.document.options.save === false` and test it for negation `&& !payload.document.options.save`

Comment: you can try-catch ``payload.document.options.save``, but it has worse performance

Comment: What is payload? Does it come from an HTTP request?

Comment: @SuhailGupta well, it's an internal object that comes from a POST JSON request.

Comment: @Lazhar Alright.

Comment: Are you using Angular2?

Answer (score 1):

There would surely be a fancy way of avoiding the `if` statements but you cannot avoid the checks. These problems are best solved by enforcing a pattern in your project.

As you said, `payload` is an HTTP request object, I will recommend you to use [`JOI`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi). You should never have these `if-checks` in the middle of the code. These `if` statements make the code buggy. Using `JOI` you could define a schema for the object. So for payload, if we define a schema, it would be something like:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    document: Joi.object().keys({
        options: Joi.object().keys({
             save: Joi.boolean()
        })
    }).required()
})

const {error, value} = Joi.validate(payload, schema);
if(error) // Handle accordingly
else {// use it carefree!}
```

This way, you would only have to check for `true/false` values for the `save` key.

So have a file:

- That lists all the HTTP request schemas
- A middleware to validate the schema
- All other operations on the request object

By following the above steps, all the subsequent code in your application will look confident and less obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lodash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get! Just pass the object and the value path.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'

if(_.get(payload,'document.options.save') === false) {
   // do stuff
}
```